# Web3.js but for C++

Tags: web3js, cpp-ethereum

Does anyone know a library for interacting with Ethereum smart contracts through C++? Just like there's web3 for JavaScript.

If not, any guidance on how I can interact with Ethereum smart contracts through C++?

Cheers.

Comment: I use json-rpc - eth.wiki/json-rpc/API